# Is a nonsingular matrix not the same as an invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

Over an arbitrary ring $R$, a matrix $A$ is said to be invertible if it has an inverse with entries in the same ring. This happens iff $\det A$ is a unit of $R$.

I've always thought that the terms "invertible" and "nonsingular" are synonymous. But I think the following problem (from Artin) suggests that they are not (at least over an arbitrary ring):

> Let $\varphi: \mathbb Z^k\to \mathbb Z^k$ be a homomorphism given by multiplication by an integer matrix $A$. Show that the image of $\varphi$ is of finite index if and only if $A$ is nonsingular and that if so, then the index is equal to $|\det A|.$

If I understand correctly, in this context "nonsingular" means $\det A\ne 0$. And this is not the same as invertible since if $A$ is invertible, then $\varphi$ is bijective, and the image is the whole $\mathbb Z^k$.

So, am I correct in saying that a matrix $A$ over a ring $R$ is by definition nonsingular if $\det A\ne 0$? And being nonsingular does not imply being invertible (unless the underlying ring is a field)?

Comment: In a ring, a non-zero element need not be a unit, hence $A$ might be not invertible although $\det(A)\ne 0$

Comment: Right, that's what I meant, but didn't state explicitly. In the context of the problem cited, if nonsingularity means $\det A\ne 0$ (which is I believe true), then (according to your remark) this doesn't imply that $A$ is invertible. This caused the question whether nonsingular and invertible are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Take the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Over $\mathbb{R}$, this has inverse
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
But, it would have no inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$.  Yet, the kernel of the map would still be trivial, hence it is nonsingular.

Comment: So in general, $A$ being nonsingular means $\det A\ne 0$, and a nonsingular matrix need not be invertible? The reason I'm confused is that Wikipedia says that nonsingular and invertible are synonyms.

Comment: @Cary I don't think that definition of "nonsingular" is common. I would personally avoid using it if the underlying ring is not a field. Wikipedia probably is assuming field coefficients.

Comment: @Cihan I can refrain from using it, but the problem is that Artin uses it, and if it "nonsingular" is interpreted as "invertible", then the problem referred to in my question is false. Anyway, I guess I should assume that "nonsingular"  means that the determinant isn't zero, at least in this context.

Answer (score 4):

A matrix $A$ is called **right-singular** if $Ax=0$ has non-trivial solutions, **left-singular** if $y^TA=0$ has non-trivial solutions, and **singular** if it is both left-singular and right-singular.

A matrix $A$ is called **left-invertible** if it has a left inverse, **right-invertible** if it has a right inverse, and **invertible** if it is a square matrix that has left and right inverses.

Determinant is not involved in the definitions of these two concepts. The usual definition of determinant does not apply in the first place if the ring is not commutative.

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix over a commutative ring $R$, so that you can speak of its determinant.

1. $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det A$ is invertible in $R$. That is, $A$ is a unit in $M_n(R)$ if and only if $\det A$ is a unit in $R$. For the "only if" part, consider $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$; for the "if" part, consider $A\operatorname{adj}(A)=\operatorname{adj}(A)A=\det(A)I$.
2. $A$ is singular if and only if $\det A$ is a zero divisor in $R$. The "only if" part can be easily proven as follows. Suppose $Ax=0$ for some $x\ne0$. Without loss of generality we may assume that the first entry of $x$ is nonzero. Construct a matrix $B$ by replacing the first column of the identity matrix by $x$. Then $\det(B)\ne0$ but $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)=0$ because the first column of $AB$ is zero.

   The proof of the "if" part is less trivial. See, e.g. chapter 9 of

   > Brown W.C. (1993), *Matrices over Commutative Rings*, Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York.

   Note that $A$ can be singular even if $\det A\ne0$; e.g. over $R=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, we have $\pmatrix{3&1\\ 1&1}\pmatrix{2\\ 2}=0$ but $\det\pmatrix{3&1\\ 1&1}=2\ne0$. While the determinant ($=2$) in this case is nonzero, it is a zero divisor.
3. It follows from (1) and (2) that $A$ is invertible **only if** $A$ is nonsingular (a more direct proof: $Ax=0\Rightarrow x=A^{-1}Ax=0$). The converse is not true. E.g. over $R=\mathbb Z$, every integer (which is a $1\times1$ matrix) $\ge2$ are nonsingular but not invertible.
4. Right-invertibility, left-invertibility and invertibility are equivalent. So are right-singularity, left-singularity and singularity. The statement in (2) can thus be rephrased as "$A$ is a zero divisor in $M_n(R)$ if and only if $\det A$ is a zero divisor in $R$."

Comment: Is this use of "left-singular" and "right-singular" standard? It's new to me. Is in the Brown's text?

Comment: @Alan I cannot recall whether these two terms are in Brown's text or not. They aren't standard in matrix theory. Nevertheless such usages of "left" or "right" are not uncommon in mathematics (e.g. right-invertible matrix or right eigenvector in matrix theory, or right-singular element in ring theory).